# Case insensitive selection of elements using XPathSelectElements

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I need to get `<aw:Child1>` elements using XPath from below xml by ignoring case.

```
<aw:Root xmlns:aw='http://www.test-works.com'>
    <aw:Child uid='Test1'>child one data 1</aw:Child>
    <aw:Child uid='Test2'>child one data 2</aw:Child>
    <aw:Child uid='Test3'>child one data 3</aw:Child>
</aw:Root>
```

Here's my code, but it never returns any elements:

```
      string markup = @"
<aw:Root xmlns:aw='http://www.test-works.com'>
    <aw:Child uid='Test1'>child one data 1</aw:Child>
    <aw:Child uid='Test2'>child one data 2</aw:Child>
    <aw:Child uid='Test3'>child one data 3</aw:Child>
</aw:Root>";
            var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(markup));
            var root = XElement.Load(reader);
            var nameTable = reader.NameTable;
            var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
            namespaceManager.AddNamespace("aw", "http://www.test-works.com");

            var inputQuery = "./aw:Child[@uid='test1']"; //Auto generated

            var elements = root.XPathSelectElements(inputQuery, namespaceManager);
            foreach (var el in elements)
                Console.WriteLine(el);
```

I get the results when I change the path to correct case

```
var inputQuery = "./aw:Child[@uid='Test1']";
```

But the elements to match are generated dynamically, and are always lowercase. Is there any way to ignore case while matching elements?

Comment: Xml is case sensitive so why you want to select element in case insensitive way? Anyways you can just select all the elements (i.e. in this case use '/*/*') and check the name/filter in the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath 1.0 translate() function to replace all the uppercase characters to lowercase.
In your case it will be:

```
var inputQuery = "./aw:Child[translate(@uid, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='test1']";
```